# jQuery load function not doing anything

Tags: jquery, include, load

I want to load an external jQuery player into my div `#player`. I have tried several addresses to find any changes but there's no content included. What am I doing wrong?

```
    // This one is okay
    $("li a").live("click", function(){
           $("#textoPequeno").load($(this).attr('href'));    
           return false;
    });

    //This one is not doing anything
    $(document).live(function() {
    $("#player").load("http://code.internuts.se/jquery/iwish/index.html");
    } );
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simpleplayer.css" type="text/css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/javascript.js"></script>



<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Opera</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="header">

            <h1 id="logo">
                <a href="#">Linux Logo</a>
            </h1>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="1.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="2.html">Navegación</a></li>
                <li><a href="3.html">Novedades</a></li>
                <li><a href="4.html">Diseño</a></li>
                <li><a href="5.html">Multimedia</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="player">
            </div>

        </div>
    <div id="imagen"></div>
    <h2 id="textoGrande"><p>Opera ahora<br /> mas acojedor...</p>
    </h2><h3 id="textoPequeno"><p>La hegemonía de Internet Explorer, el navegador web de Microsoft, poco a poco va llegando a su fin. Durante los últimos años hemos asistido a la aparición de nuevos navegadores que han explotado las carencias de Internet Explorer, incorporando nuevas características ausentes en éste.</p>

    </h3></div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: I don't see $(document).ready(function(){
   // Your code here
 }); anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#player").load("http://code.internuts.se/jquery/iwish/index.html");

   // include this in the document.ready as well because in order to attache the events the document needs to be ready. 
   $("li a").live("click", function(){
           $("#textoPequeno").load($(this).attr('href'));    
           return false;
    });
} );
```

Even after making this change i still suspect you will run into the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) limitation which restricts cross domain ajax requests, i'm guessing this is not your domain.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX calls are restricted to **Same Origin Policy**: it wont work for loading content thats outside your domain.

Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your call is doing what you think it is. Try this instead...

```
$(function() {
    $("#player").load("http://code.internuts.se/jquery/iwish/index.html");
});
```

`$(....)` is the jQuery shorthand for document.ready. A function passed as a parameter to jQuery will be bound to document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `jQuery.live()`, a function for binding event handlers for DOM elements being changed or replaced - I think what you want here is `jQuery.ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#player").load("http://code.internuts.se/jquery/iwish/index.html");
});
```

This can also simplified as:

```
$(function() {
   $("#player").load(...);
});
```